# My wallet won't load because it says it contained a duplicate transaction. Are my coins lost forever or can i load it some other way?

Tags: wallet, doublespend, multibit

Question pretty much says my dilemma. Wallet won't load due to a "duplicate transaction" which I thought could not happen. I use multibit btw, if that helps. Please tell me I can load my wallet somehow.

Comment: Because this relates to Multibit rather than the standard client, I don't think it's a duplicate question. You might like to take a look at the information regarding the same issue for the standard client though: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/3654/516 http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/4152/516

Comment: SHould have mentioned, I didn't spend bitcoin, I was recieving it.

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug that was fixed in v0.4.1 (26 June 2012) so I presume you are running an earlier version. If you download the latest version from multibit.org your wallet should load ok.

Sorry for the inconvenience.